# Solr DihR error 500

Tags: sql-server, solr, dih

I have this error while using DiH for importing data from SQL Server to Solr for indexing:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more 

detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler' at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:423) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459) at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373) ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing class file, so add apache-solr-dataimporthandler(version).jar in "dist" directory and all the jars in "contrib\dataimporthandler\lib" to path.